# Change root folder on HTML links

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have a bunch of HTML files with link tags like this:

```
[...]
<a href="/file1.php">Link 1</a>
<a href="/file2.php">Link 2</a>
<a href="/file3.php">Link 3</a>
[...]
```

The website is inside a folder on the server, e.g. `http://www.website.com/folder/`, but links beggining with `/` point to the root, e.g. `http://www.website.com/`, but the files `file1.php`, `file2.php`, `file3.php`, etc. are inside the folder.

How would I be able to make the links act as if the root folder were the folder where they are, without changing HTML contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a internal redirect like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The condition is to redirect only PHP files to the folder, if that gives you a loop you can go with a more specific one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /folder/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

With `RewriteBase` something like this:

```
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Prix, thanks for the answer but it didn't work. I forgot to mention, but I cannot change the .htaccess that is on the root folder.   That configuration would have to be done in a .htaccess file inside http://www.website.com/folder/, not on .htaccess on the root http://www.website.com/.

Comment: @JoãoPaulin if u want a rule executed on the root folder then it must be applied on the root folder htaccess as it will follow hierarchy.

Comment: Prix, won't it be possible to put a .htaccess file inside http://website.com/folder/ to make the files sees http://website.com/folder/ as if it were root, making its links search inside http://website.com/folder/ instead of http://website.com/?

Comment: @JoãoPaulin nope I don't think so, you could try using `RewriteBase /folder/` however that will not work because the URLs are hardcoded on your files which will by default attach your domain to URLs starting with `/`